# Eigenmatrix of a Wishart Matrix

Tags: probability, random-matrices

A lot of papers mention statements of the form "The Eigenmatrix of a Wishart matrix are uniformly distributed on a sphere of $P$ dimensions" but I am having a hard time finding the conditions under which this result holds.

For instance, if the sample size is $N = 10^{23}$, then,won't the sample eigenvectors be concentrated in a small region?